# How to change the bkcolor of the document's view

Tags: view, mfc, background-color

How to change the bkcolor of the document's view when edit the document,just like the visual studio I can choose the favourites color for the backgroundcolor,is there some apis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you talking about edit control with syntax coloring. So, for example, simple coloring [control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28619/CUltraPadWnd-A-Simple-Syntax-Coloring-Control-Base):

or how to use [Scintilla](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4440/Using-Scintilla-for-syntax-coloring-in-MFC) in your MFGC project:

Comment: I would like to have a try on Scintilla，Thanks